# android sqlite3 database is locked

Tags: android, sqlite

When running `sqlite3` on my android emulator's database, I tried to run `select * from mytable where id = 4`, but I got `database is locked`.

I was able to access it earlier today. I'm sure it's the database that my emulator is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the process that is using it to finish. It's locked because some operation is synchronized.